# Graphic problem with Ubuntu 20.04 - random pixelated areas

Tags: 20.04, graphics

I am experiencing a problem since I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS 13. Often the screen shows pixelated areas as the one in the figures below.

[image]
[image]

On the website I saw people experiencing similar problems, but couldn't find a solution.

The details of my graphic card are the following:

```
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=3840x2400 visual=truecolor xres=3840 yres=2400
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:206 memory:603e000000-603effffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!